# Is a 3mm x 15mm x 150mm copper strip enough for 80A soldered to a 1oz PCB

Tags: pcb-design

I am in a weird predicament where i can only go 1oz PCB. JLCPCB currently dont offer 2oz on 4 layer with black colored pcb. I am making a LED driver circuit with 8 channels and each of them consumes about 10A. I am spaced constrained on the main trace delivering to each of the channel with only about 180mm x 25mm.

I was thinking of not placing a solder paste on the trace and solder a  3mm thick 15mm x 150mm copper strip.

[image]

Would that be enough? if not if i double the thickness to 6mm will it still be not enough ?

Also the bottom copper is mostly ground do i need to place a buss bar there too ?

Comment: Compare cross section against wire gauges

Comment: @DKNguyen I did have a look at the [current carry capacity](https://www.sab-cable.com/cables-wires-harnessing-temperature-measurement/technical-data/cables-and-wires/instructions-for-the-safe-application-of-cables/boundary-conditions/calculate-wire-cross-section-current-carrying-capacity-table.html) of the copper bar and i am below 1/2 of its limits (45mm2 is about >130A at wost). But is it really that straight forward?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is a bus bar and at least one fabricator I know actually spot weld them using a separate gerber layer as a guide (on the *inside* of the board).

I think you were talking about solder *mask* not *paste*. By the way, not putting mask is a standard trick to raise ampacity since it radiates heat better.

Also I think you are worrying too much, unless your board has to survive at very high ambient temperatures. If I remember correctly 1oz/ft of copper is the european 35µm copper plating. With 25mm of width is 0.875mmsq of cross section. That's so big it goes of the experimental data… they have graphs up to 0.5mmsq. Your board alone will keep about 20A with a temperature raise of 40°C and it's 35µm thick, do the math. Also the busbar dissipates better since it has no coating and the sides are exposed.

I would be more worried about thermal dilation. Thankfully it's short otherwise you risk the bar bending the board when heating up.

Comment: is 60 - 70 °C  okay for a pcb board besubjected to for long period of times?

Comment: until 80°C usually no problems at all. Consider that the usual operating range is up to 40°C ambient, so usually you put the operational heat rise to +40°C